# How to make environment variables available to Apache, started as a service?

Tags: php, apache, environment-variables

I know that adding some environment variables to `/etc/environment` will make them available system-wide, adding them to `/etc/profile` , `~/.bashrc` or equivalent, will make available to a specific user... all this however applies to *interactive* sessions. When Apache is started as a `systemd` service, it is a non-interactive session so it does not see those environment variables. Can I have Apache parse an `.env` file which contains lines like

```
env1=foo
env2=bar
...
```

and then could access them in my PHP code with `$_SERVER['foo']` , etc. **Of course, I would like to achive the same for other `systemd` services too, so is there any specific file that provides env variables for services?**

Comment: There are a bunch of libraries to allow PHP to read .env files, so is that enough or are them some specific reasons for wanting Apache to read them instead?

Comment: No @NigelRen I do not want Apache specifically to read them, I just want to make sure every Systemd service (might also be a node.js application as a service) to be able to have automatic access to them

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [SetEnv](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_env.html#setenv) directive in the site's Apache configuration file to set environment variables for that site, like this:

```
SetEnv DATABASE_NAME foo
```

This needs to go inside the `<VirtualHost>` directive.

Once you have restarted the server this data should be accessible either via the `$_ENV` superglobal or [getenv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php). The downside of this approach is that if your application includes anything that isn't executed by Apache, such as a queue worker or console command, it won't have access to the same variables unless you duplicate them in an appropriate place (eg your `.bashrc`).

Or you can use a library like [DotEnv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv).

Comment: But how later on you can include it somewhere inside another *.conf ?
Running `SetEnv MY_PATH "/my/personal/venv/bin` and then inside a vhost `SetEnv PATH "${MY_PATH}:${PATH}"` - then it just paste it as a string ( when running the webpage ): `PATH is "${MY_PATH}:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"`

Answer (score 2):

Apache has `envvars` file that is located in `$prefix/bin/envvars` by default when built from source. Debian has it located in `/etc/apache2` directory afaik. In this file you can modify the environment before `httpd` process is started, eg. `export env1=foo`

`envvars` is generally interpreted when Apache is started automatically as a service or by using `apachectl` command, not when `httpd` is invoked directly. So if you rely on environment variables set in `envvars`, make sure to include it if you have homebrewn startup scripts.

Comment: Worked flawlessly! I had a PHP docker with Apache and I was able to read env var, but after adding ssh and running it with `service ssh start` and `service apache2 start` in a sh file variables were gone! 
It's 15 past 1 AM, Now I can sleep in peace.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `auto_prepend_file` within your `VirtualHost` directive to have PHP include a file before every request:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName myserver.com
DocumentRoot /path/to/doc/root/

php_value auto_prepend_file "/path/to/my/env_settings.php"

</VirtualHost>
```

'env_settings.php' can contain any valid php, so you should be able to set any variables you wish and have them available in global scope.